# High resolution sleep in kernel thread?

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, real-time

What is the correct way to sleep to us resolution in a thread?

I'm trying to write a device driver and I need to keep a pin high for a certain number of us after a GPIO interrupt.

My plan is to create a kernel module for GPIO interrupt which will set the pin high and spawn a kernel thread to bring it low after a certain time.

Will this work?

Comment: that depends a bit – how bad is it when you're leaving the pin high for longer than intended? I don't think you'd spawn a thread each time, in an interrupt handling context, though.

Comment: and: can you maybe on your hardware instead utilize a hardware PWM/counter unit to make that one-shot high pulse of defined duration?

Comment: I don't think hardware PWM will work, I was looking at trying to create a delayed tasklet? from the interrupt routine. Would this work?

In general I don't fully understand how kernel threads spawned in an interrupt handler work, does the interrupt handler block until the kernel thread is finished?

Comment: no, that sounds like a bad idea, but this is really something that hardware PWM/timer units were meant for: "toggle the state of this GPIO when you count down to zero, and start counting NOW" is literally what they are designed to do.

Comment: you can't do complicated stuff in interrupt handlers, and doing other things that might themself cause new interrupts is definitely a recipe for disaster.

Comment: But does a kernel thread spawned in an interrupt delay the interrupt handler?

Comment: Tasklets appear to be a way to do what I want, what is bad about using them?

Comment: honestly, from an electrical engineer's point of view, you want to hold a GPIO high after some event for a defined time. That's the job of hardware, and you have such hardware, namely the PWM/timer units. Taskslets are *not* a way to do what you want, because you don't have a hard-real-time operating system, but Linux. Even Linux with RT patches cannot guarantee reentrance at a specific into a timed task, because you have no control over whether a higher-prioritized interrup occurs before or during your interrupt handling. None of this is even a problem to begin with if you just use a pwm unit

Comment: I'm using a Pi5 and it doesn't appear there is a one shot PWM option. I didn't see an option for an extra timer I could use either. The signal duration controls a cameras exposure time so it doesn't have to be perfect, just approximately correct.

Comment: I considered using an extra MCU too but, it's so much cleaner just using the Pi.

Comment: the pi has a pwm/timer unit, definitely. It's meant for these kinds of things. thousands of people are using that, for example to drive WS2812 "neopixel" addressable RGB LED strips.

Comment: Like I said it's not one shot though.

Comment: Do you know if threaded interrupts can be re-entrant? That's a solution too though as I only want the pulse every 10 triggers.

Comment: It is one shot, otherwise you couldn't control a WS2812 with it. I've used that thing. Stop trying to make software do something it's not meant to.

Comment: The new Pi is not one shot, at least from what I read in the datasheet

Comment: Also I think work queues will do what I want.

Comment: for the fourth time, you can't let software do something that you need the determinism of hardware for. You can dig up more kernel concepts all you want, but this is a hardware job, and you have hardware that can do it, and I've even pointed you to example usage where you can just look up source code; this is my last comment here: Really, a timer unit that can deassert an output as soon as its counter reaches zero is so basic, you can assume *every* SoC has that. And for good reason, it is really something you need quite often.